# I got ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 3 when try implementing CTC Loss on my LSTM Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have an LSTM Model:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dropout, Dense, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input_layer = Input(shape=(11, 3))
lstm_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
dropout_1 = Dropout(0.25)(lstm_1)
lstm_2 = LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=True)(dropout_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.1)(lstm_2)
lstm_3 = LSTM(units=16)(dropout_2)
dense_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(lstm_3)
batch_norm_1 = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(dense_1)
dense_2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(batch_norm_1)
dense_3 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(dense_2)
output_layer = Dense(units=max_text_words, activation='relu')(dense_3)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

reduce_lr_on_plateau_callback= keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='mse', factor= 0.9, patience=1, min_lr=1e-7, min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=10)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005), metrics=['mse'])
```

And i got the CTCLoss from [here[1](https://keras.io/examples/audio/ctc_asr/)

```py
def CTCLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Compute the training-time loss value
    batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
    input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
    label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

    input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
    label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

    loss = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
    return loss
```

When i train the model

```py
num_epochs = 1000
num_batch_size = 64

# history = model.fit(x_train_windowed, y_train_padded, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(x_test_windowed, y_test_padded))
history = model.fit(x_train_windowed, y_train_padded, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(x_test_windowed, y_test_padded), callbacks=[reduce_lr_on_plateau_callback])
```

I got this error saying that i need to add more dimension to my data?

```py
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "<ipython-input-89-a6830365d816>", line 10, in CTCLoss  *
        loss = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 7046, in ctc_batch_cost
        tf.compat.v1.transpose(y_pred, perm=[1, 0, 2]) + epsilon()

    ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 3 for '{{node CTCLoss/transpose_2}} = Transpose[T=DT_FLOAT, Tperm=DT_INT32](model_17/dense_107/Relu, CTCLoss/transpose_2/perm)' with input shapes: [?,6], [3].
```

Can someone please explain whats wrong here?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @gone Unfortunately no, someone told me change the model to a class based model might solve the problem. Haven't try it though